# ldapsearch and kerberos authentication

Tags: debian, kerberos

I can successfully connect and search to an Active Directory domain controller using ldapsearch. I am using the `-x` option, to specify a username/password authentication (password being specified by `-W` and username by `-D`).

I currently need to dump directory from a MIT-kerberos domain. Kerberos is the only protocol available for authentication. I can retrieve a kerberos TGT ticket with `kinit`. I am using these command lines:

```
ldapsearch  -Y SASL -b "REALM.INC" -H ldap://kerberos_IP_address
-> ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
  additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found

ldapsearch -o "mech=GSSAPI" ...
-> Invalid general option name: mech
```

How can I authenticate with kerberos using ldapsearch?

Many thanks for your help&replies

Comment: What happened when you do ldapsearch  -H ldap://kerberos_IP_address -U administrator -s base -b  "CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com" -Y GSSAPI  -s sub "(cn=*)" ? Does klist show valid tickets in cache ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be missing the [`libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit) package.

Without:

```
# ldapsearch -H ldap://dc1 -Y GSSAPI -b 'DC=ad-test,DC=vx'
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Unknown authentication method (-6)
    additional info: SASL(-4): no mechanism available: No worthy mechs found
```

Install:

```
# apt install libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
```

With:

```
# ldapsearch -H ldap://dc1 -Y GSSAPI -b 'DC=ad-test,DC=vx'
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: Administrator@AD-TEST.VX
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
...
```

SASL is enabled by default, and will auto-detect a compatible mechanism, so specifying `-Y GSSAPI` isn't even necessary:

```
# ldapsearch -H ldap://dc1 -b 'DC=ad-test,DC=vx'
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: Administrator@AD-TEST.VX
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`-Y` is used to specify the SASL mechanism, which will probably be `GSSAPI`, though could be `GSS-SPNEGO`. Also, base dn must be in dn syntax (i.e., `dc=example,dc=com`), not domain syntax (`example.com`).

```
$ ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base supportedSASLMechanisms -H ldap://192.0.2.1/
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI

$ ldapsearch -Y GSSAPI -b dc=example,dc=com -H ldap://192.0.2.1/

$ ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base supportedSASLMechanisms -H ldap://192.0.2.2/
dn:
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSS-SPNEGO
supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI
```

Answer (score 1):

depending on your ldapsearch & OS version, you can try to first authenticate to kerberos using kinit and "cache" your ticket, use it in a kerberos env variable, and then let ldapsearch use this variable, with something like this :

```
kinit -c /tmp/<yourlogin>.cc.tmp <yourlogin>
export KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/<yourlogin>.cc.tmp
ldapsearch -Tx -h <host> -p <port> -Y GSSAPI -b "dc=example,dc=com" cn=*
```

Comment: `-T` means something different to debian / OpenLDAP than it does to Solaris.

Comment: my commands run perfectly on a Linux RHEL 6.x, didn't try on debian tho, but it should work anyway assuming that the variable is set and the -Y is passed i suppose, thanks for the info btw

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04, installing the `libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit` library and using `kinit` to get a Kerberos cookie isn't all I need to do.
Our Active Directory server no longer supports plain LDAP, so we need to use `ldaps`, which produces the following issue:

> ```
> $ ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://our.ad.server -b 'DC=our,DC=ad,DC=domain' -s sub '(samaccountname=rpost)' mail cn title
> SASL/GSS-SPNEGO authentication started
> ldap_sasl_interactive_bind: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
>         additional info: 00002029: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906AC, comment: Cannot bind using sign/seal on a connection on which TLS or SSL is in effect, data 0, v4f7c
> ```

I also need to pass certain SSL options, either on the command line:

> ```
> $ ldapsearch -O minssf=0,maxssf=0 -LLL -H ldaps://our.ad.server -b 'DC=our,DC=ad,DC=domain' -s sub '(samaccountname=rpost)' mail cn title
> ```

or by [adding them to `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/731).

Comment: That's a separate issue, with a different cause (because you're using ldaps:// – OP was using ldap:// relying on Kerberos-provided encryption) and with different symptoms (the error message is entirely different from OP's).

Comment: Good point, thanks; answer amended. This may still be helpful here, since we switched from `ldap` to `ldaps` and no doubt others did, too. Or shall I just remove it?

Comment: You could keep it but it nevertheless seems unrelated, so I'd probably say create a whole new thread – describe your own situation in the question and immediately post your own answer, which is an option at SF/SO.

Comment: AD has mandatory channel binding now. One implication is no more basic authentication over LDAP 389/3268. And a couple other gotchas for older code that can't handle a token. And possibly code that has custom SASL auth.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/2020-2023-and-2024-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a